# I have these two similar classes. What design would you use to factorize code?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, code-duplication

I have a quite complicated graph-like data structure. For the sake of clarity, let's simplify it to:

```
class Node;
class AbstractEdge { void foo() {} };
class Edge1: public AbstractEdge { void bar1() {} };
class Edge2: public AbstractEdge { void bar2() {} };
```

As you can see, our graph is not like any other graph: there exists two kinds of edge, both inheriting from AbstractEdge. This design cannot be changed. Now, assume that I have to design two classes along the lines of:

```
class OrientedEdge1
{
  Edge1 * edge;
  bool orientation;

  void foo() { edge->foo(); } 
  void bar1() { edge->bar1(); }
}

class OrientedEdge2
{
  Edge2 * edge;
  bool orientation;

  void foo() { edge->foo(); }
  void bar2() { edge->bar2(); }
}
```

In practice, OrientedEdge1::foo() and OrientedEdge2::foo() are much longer than just calling a single method, but the idea is that they are identical, calling only methods inherited from AbstractEdge.

What design would you use to factorize code? I am thinking of three approaches:

## 1. Using free functions

```
foo_impl(AbstractEdge * edge) { edge->foo(); }

class OrientedEdge1
{
  Edge1 * edge;
  bool orientation;

  void foo() { foo_impl(edge); }
  void bar1() { edge->bar1(); }
}

class OrientedEdge2
{
  Edge2 * edge;
  bool orientation;

  void foo() { foo_impl(edge); }
  void bar2() { edge->bar2(); }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Very simple solution, much better than not factorizing at all.

**Cons:**

- Not all methods can be implemented as free functions.
- The declaration code is still duplicated.

## 2. Using inheritance

```
class AbstractOrientedEdge
{
  AbstractEdge * edge;
  bool orientation;

  void foo() { edge->foo(); }
}

class OrientedEdge1: public AbstractOrientedEdge
{
  Egde1 * edge1() { return static_cast<Egde1*>(edge); }

  void bar1() { edge1()->bar1(); }
}

class OrientedEdge2: public AbstractOrientedEdge
{
  Egde2 * edge2() { return static_cast<Egde2*>(edge); }

  void bar2() { edge2()->bar2(); }
}
```

**Pros:**

- More factorization.
- I do not plan to use these two classes polymorphically, but who knows, maybe the fact that they are related by inheritance might turn useful in the future.

**Cons:**

- Need care in constructors/setters to enforce that OrientedEdge1::edge always points to a Egde1*.
- Somehow, the static_cast feels wrong.

## 3. Using templates

```
template <class EdgeT>
class OrientedEdge
{
  EdgeT * edge;
  bool orientation;

  void foo() { edge->foo(); }
}

class OrientedEdge1: public OrientedEdge<Edge1>
{
  void bar1() { edge->bar1(); }
}

class OrientedEdge2: public OrientedEdge<Edge2>
{
  void bar2() { edge->bar2(); }
}
```

**Pros:**

- Most factorization.
- The pointer stored in both classes has the correct type, no casting needed.

**Cons:**

- Need to keep implementation of shared code in the header, which force to include AbstractEdge.h (could be avoided with forward declarations with previous approaches).

Questions: Which approach would you tend to use? Do you have any other solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Don't let considerations of build efficiency guide the design. Buy a faster build machine if it really becomes a problem. But it's most probably just premature build-optimization.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf My concern for including "AbstractEdge.h" is not about build time, but about circular dependencies. Indeed, with design #3, it prevents AbstractEdge (or any class needed to implement OrientedEdge), to have OrientedEdge data members, forcing to have pointers instead when there is otherwise no need. This situation *does* happen in my specific case. Actually, I implemented #3 a long time ago, but now I'm doing some refactoring and it is a good time to consider changing to another architecture for this class.

Comment: Oh, come on.... put on hold, really? "Answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions": what's wrong about hearing the opinion of somebody more experienced than me, to help me take a decision? "rather than facts, references, or specific expertise": I do believe that software architecture require specific expertise, and based on experience, there might be a consensus that using one approach is preferable than another in that specific use case, which I would love to know. Or know about alternative approaches, as already suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 3.

3 removes duplicate boilerplate, 1 moves implementation wherever I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "1 and 3"? Do you mean "1 or 3", or you actually mean to combine both? Hmmm.... let me think. That latter idea is interesting. I was about to say, "how combining would be helpful?", but after some thinking it is actually helpful. You still have to include "AbstractEdge.h", "Edge1.h", and "Edge2.h" (because you need to know the inheritance relation at compile time to call the free function, unless you perform a dynamic_cast), but it makes possible to avoid including other headers needed for the implementation of the free function. Thx, I didn't think about that!

Comment: (note: I'll wait to see if there are other interesting answers before accepting yours)

Comment: Since my answer is now on hold anyway, no one can add another answer. Thx for taking the time to give your advice, it's the option I'll do :-) Cheers!